# How to start Hangouts phonecall from website

Tags: html, google-hangouts

Recently, [Google enhanced](http://googleblog.blogspot.nl/2014/09/call-me-maybe-introducing-free-voice.html) the possibilities to make phonecalls. Money saving on your mobile, and the only way (nearly...) to make calls from a Chromebook.
How do I start a phonecall from a website? I am familiar with

```
<a href="tel:5551234567">Call (555)123-4567</a>
```

as a general approach, not supported on Chromebook.
Also I know how to Skype

```
<a href="callto:5551234567">Call (555)123-4567</a>
```

But can anyone tell me how to do this for Hangout?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc is here : https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button
I think that's what you want !

Comment: Thnx. It's not what I _want_ (i.e. a simple formula like tel: or callto:). But it might be what I _need_. However this seems to me to be the 'old' way of inviting people to an hangout. It involves creating an app etc.